# List of Cities of Turkey on single Click Using JVMap

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Turkey Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFJIZ.png)

I want all name of cities of turkey on click, In image the map has shown, when i click specific city in map, it showed me name in text of that specific city but i want to get all the city names on single click,

Below is code of JavaScript to get single city name

```
</scipt>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        //Sehir nufuslarina gore renk paleti olusturulmustur. Iptal icin values degerini silmeniz yeterli
        var sehir_nufus = {
            "1": "82700", "2": "26480", "3": "31530", "4": "22820", "5": "15550", "6": "205790", "7": "78830", "8": "7860", "9": "39940", "10": "49210", "11": "9120", "12": "10690", "13": "14100", "14": "11890", "15": "10520", "16": "105260", "17": "23240", "18": "4750", "19": "25350", "20": "41100", "21": "63430", "22": "17890", "23": "25570", "24": "9650", "25": "37350", "26": "32300", "27": "68240", "28": "21140", "29": "5430", "30": "10700", "31": "58560", "32": "19460", "33": "66610", "34": "564890", "35": "166200", "36": "12820", "37": "13950", "38": "52910", "39": "14710", "40": "9610", "41": "57790", "42": "84160", "43": "26490", "44": "32500", "45": "56550", "46": "43550", "47": "33240", "48": "32510", "49": "17550", "50": "12250", "51": "12670", "52": "30760", "53": "12740", "54": "36390", "55": "55280", "56": "12230", "57": "9010", "58": "27230", "59": "32800", "60": "28180", "61": "32970", "62": "3760", "63": "63760", "64": "14550", "65": "47470", "66": "20700", "67": "27350", "68": "15470", "69": "3700", "70": "9600", "71": "13350", "72": "21840", "73": "17440", "74": "7470", "75": "5050", "76": "7670", "77": "7340", "78": "9310", "79": "5240", "80": "21350", "81": "14580"
        };

        jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
            map: 'turkey_tr',
            borderOpacity: 0.25,
            borderWidth: 1,
            color: '#f4f3f0',
            enableZoom: true,
            hoverColor: '#999999',
            values: sehir_nufus, //iptal icin yorum icine aliniz! 
            hoverOpacity: null,
            scaleColors: ['#FFFFFF', '#FF0000'],
            selectedColor: '#c9dfaf',
            selectedRegion: null,
            showTooltip: true,
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
            onRegionClick: function(element, code, region) {
                var message = 'You clicked "'
                             + region
                             + '" which has the code: '
                             + code.toUpperCase();
                alert(message);
            }
        });
    });
</scipt>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$("#click-button-id").click(function(){

    // write your code here to list cities

});
```

Comment: this is fine, but after detecting that button has been clicked as you suggest, how will i retrieve all cities, i mean, what would be the inner code of this function?

Comment: please give me js file you used for that

Comment: it's okay, I used database for that. It is resolved now.